# Mushroom identification, Hungary

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I've found these growing on regular lawn, near some pine trees. In Europe, Hungary, Szada, near the end of October. Could you please help identify it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Particularly for fungi, treat any ID with caution - don't eat until confirmed by a local expert.